# How to refresh symlink in PHP-FPM under apache

Tags: php, apache, cgi

I have PHP-FPM running under Apache, and I use symlinks to switch between releases, like `/html -> /release/1`

However it is a well-know problem that symlinked files are cached under PHP-FPM. The easiest [solution](https://www.tobymackenzie.com/blog/2021/02/08/php-fpm-apache-caching-symlinks/) is just to reload PHP-FPM, there are also suggestions how to handle this problem under Nginx using [$realpath_root](https://deployer.org/docs/7.x/avoid-php-fpm-reloading) variable.

Is there an equivalent option for apache?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP opcache reset + symlink-style deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23737627/php-opcache-reset-symlink-style-deployment)

Comment: fastcgi_param  is nginx specific, so won't work under apache, but need to check the cachetool mentioned.

Comment: apache has ProxyFCGISetEnvIf directive (available in version 2.4.26 and later), but what would be the equivalent for $realpath_root and $fastcgi_script_name?