# Php artisan optimize is failing on production server

Tags: laravel

Running `composer install` on a production server via a bash script is failing at `post-install-cmd` `php artisan optimize` with the error `There are no commands defined in the "jwt" namespace`.

To try to resolve the issue I added the following commands before `php artisan optimize`

`"php artisan clear-compiled",
 "php artisan cache:clear",
 "php artisan config:clear",
 "php artisan config:cache",`

Running `composer install` locally works fine. I can run the commands through a script locally without a problem.

The failure is happening while running `composer install` through a script on the production server. If I log onto the server and run the commands manually I do not generate the error.

Not sure how to debug, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a pre-install event inside of your `composer.json` file on the server, note that this event works only if your `composer.lock` is present and you ran `composer install`:

```
"scripts": {
    "pre-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan config:clear"
    ],
...
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure I did that. For others who run into the situation I ended up downgrading to laravel 5.4 as this was a result of upgrading to laravel 5.5 and 5.6. It may be coming from `dingo/api`... with the error being so vague I just couldn't find the source